# Is there any difference between Ruby class method calling with in class method with and without self?

Tags: ruby

I am little bit curious about to know that, is there any difference between below two approaches?

1. Calling class method with in class method using self

   ```
   class Test
     def self.foo
      puts 'Welcome to ruby'
     end

    def self.bar
     self.foo
    end

   end
   ```

   `Test.bar`  # Welcome to ruby
2. Calling class method with in class method without self

   ```
   class Test
     def self.foo
      puts 'Welcome to ruby'
     end

    def self.bar
     foo
    end

   end
   ```

   `Test.bar`  # Welcome to ruby

Comment: Note that this is not specific for class methods, it's the same for calling instance methods.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference. But not in your example. But if `foo` was a `private` class method, then your first version would raise an exception, because you call `foo` with an explicit receiver:

```
class Test
  def self.foo
    puts 'Welcome to ruby'
  end
  private_class_method :foo

  def self.bar
    self.foo
  end
end

Test.bar
#=> NoMethodError: private method `foo' called for Test:Class
```

But the second version would still work:

```
class Test
  def self.foo
    puts 'Welcome to ruby'
  end
  private_class_method :foo

  def self.bar
    foo
  end
end

Test.bar
#=> "Welcome to ruby"
```

Comment: Another difference: if there was a local variable `foo`, `foo` would refer to that variable and `self.foo` would refer to the method.